# resource annotation in soapHandler implemantation

Tags: web-services, annotations, jax-ws, soapheader, soaphandler

I have read few tutorials about soap handlers and some of them uses only handler chain but some of them use both @resource annotation and handler chain xml. I am confused if @resource is needed to use or not. If yes why exactly I need to use it?

Answer (score 0):

The [`@Resource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) annotation marks a resource that is needed by the application. This annotation may be applied to an application component class, or to fields or methods of the component class. When the annotation is applied to a field or method, the container will inject an instance of the requested resource into the application component when the component is initialized. If the annotation is applied to the component class, the annotation declares a resource that the application will look up at runtime.

The [`WebServiceContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceContext.html) object that injected by using [`@Resource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) annotation, wraps the [`MessageContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/MessageContext.html) that includes the [`SOAPMessage`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html), and also includes various information about the HTTP connection that carried the [`SOAPMessage`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html). The web container will then initialize the [`WebServiceContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceContext.html) reference whenever a service request arrives. This allows web methods to have access to the HTTP headers in the HTTP request that is carrying the request, as well as to the [`SOAPMessageContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPMessageContext.html), SOAP headers, and [`SOAPMessage`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html).

Why in one case uses [`@Resource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) annotation and in other case not? Because in one case all necessary information can be retrieved from objects of these classes ([`SOAPMessageContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPMessageContext.html), [`SOAPMessage`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html), etc) and these objects available via  implementation of [`LogicalHandler`](https://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/blog/entry/jaxws-handler-tutorial) interface or [`SOAPMessageContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/soap/SOAPMessageContext.html) interface. In other case all necessary information can be retrieved directly from injected [`WebServiceContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceContext.html).

See Also:

- [Annotation Type Resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html)
- [Adding JAX-WS handlers to web services and SOAP clients](https://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/blog/entry/jaxws-handler-tutorial)
- [Creating and Using SOAP Message Handlers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html#wp261459)
- [JAX-WS Message Handlers Using Netbeans](http://gcmuganda.faculty.noctrl.edu/classes/Spring12/615/Lab4/CSC615Spring12MessageHandlersLab.html)